# Detecting type inclusion in std::tuple at compile time

Tags: c++, c++20

My goal is to write a function that:

1. is callable at compile time
2. takes a template argument `Tuple` that represents an arbitrary std::tuple
3. takes a template argument `Match` that represents the type to test for
4. returns true if the tuple has 1+ element of type Match

I'm on GCC 10.2, which I can upgrade if needed. I could also switch to Clang. I'm avoiding Boost, but also starting to feel like its inclusion in my project is inevitable.

If C++20 would allow the `idx` variable as a compile-time constant, I would be done. However, that didn't make it into the standard:

```
template<typename Tuple, typename Match>
consteval bool tuple_holds()
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
    constexpr auto all = std::ranges::iota_view{std::size_t{0}, size};

    for (const auto idx : all) {
        // This doesn't work, as idx is not available as a compile-time constant
        using Type = std::tuple_element<idx, Tuple>::type;

        if (std::is_same<Type, Match>::value) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


using A = std::tuple<float, int>;


int main()
{
    static_assert(tuple_holds<A, int>());
    static_assert(tuple_holds<A, float>());
}
```

I suspect the answer lies in SFINAE, but I'm unsure of how to get further.

Comment: It's not actually clear in your question that your attempt doesn't work, and it would help if it were.  Is your question _why_ it doesn't work or simply _how_ to solve the problem?

Comment: Good point @Barry. I hope my update makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution that is pretty similar to @HolyBlackCat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331394/8372853), but uses `std::disjunction` instead of a fold-expression, and can be used the same way you have in your question (it doesn't require `::value` for the usage):

```
template<typename, typename>
struct tuple_holds;

template<typename ...Ts, typename T>
struct tuple_holds<std::tuple<Ts...>, T> 
  : std::disjunction<std::is_same<Ts, T>...> {};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j1n4h9).

Comment: This was downvoted without an explanation, but it works beautifully

Answer (score 8):

You don't need fancy C++20 features to do it.

```
template <typename, typename>
struct tuple_holds {};

template <typename ...A, typename B>
struct tuple_holds<std::tuple<A...>, B>
    : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<A, B> || ...)>
{};
```

Usage: `tuple_holds<std::tuple<A, B>, C>::value`.

Answer (score 4):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_containsl_v), this is a short one-line (as always):

```
template <typename Tuple, typename Match>
static constexpr bool tuple_holds = mp_contains<Tuple, Match>::value;
```

---

This doesn't work:

```
for (const auto idx : all) {
    using Type = std::tuple_element<idx, Tuple>::type;

    if (std::is_same<Type, Match>::value) {
```

Because you need `idx` to be a *constant expression* in order to be usable as a template argument, and `idx` is not a constant expression. You need to have something like a `constexpr` variable for this. This was one of the motivations for the [expansion statements](https://wg21.link/p1306) language feature - which would've allowed you to write:

```
template for (constexpr auto idx : all)
```

Allowing you to use `idx` as a template argument - by basically instantiating the body of the `for` loop on each iteration. But we don't have that yet.

Answer (score 1):

For a pre-C++17 solution not dependent on fold expressions, you can use a simple recursive template.

```
// Base: Provide no constant when first argument is not std::tuple<...>
template <typename, typename>
struct tuple_holds {};

// Termination: true
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct tuple_holds<std::tuple<T, Args...>, T> : std::true_type {};

// Termination: false
template <typename T>
struct tuple_holds<std::tuple<>, T> : std::false_type {};

// Recursive
template <typename T, typename THead, typename... TTail>
struct tuple_holds<std::tuple<THead, TTail...>, T> : tuple_holds<std::tuple<TTail...>, T> {};
```